# How to tell a technical support call center worker that I am technically inclined?

Tags: phone

Sometimes I just want to scream at people "I know what I'm talking about!". Ideally, I'd like a more polite way of saying this that won't be taken offensively, and can be said at the beginning of a call to avoid the "have you tried turning it off and on again" and similar portions.

I have tried many things, including:

- "I know what I'm talking about" - is impolite, annoys them, doesn't work
- "Can you skip that part? I've already done that" - Sometimes it works, sometimes they don't believe me, sometimes they tell me they can't(‽)
- Purposefully dropping hints ranging from very subtle to not subtle at all
- ["Shibboleet"](https://xkcd.com/806/) - response is one of "What?", "Huh?", or "Sorry?"
- "Can I speak to a technician?" - response is either a large dollar amount per hour, "No", or a redirect to a supervisor
- "Can I speack to a supervisor?" - if I get a supervisor, they don't help anymore than the first person

And nothing seems to work. Either the message doesn't get across, or they don't believe me, or *something*. Since I've exausted all the conventional solutions, I've started looking into unconventional solutions (perhaps if I speak klingon to them?).

P.S. Is there a better name than "technical support call center worker"?

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks SE, this site is not about how to do telephone calls. Please read the tour. With that being said, I  would politely tell them what you've already done, and ask for further advice. Most likely will they put you through to the 2nd level support this guys...

Comment: @holroy I have reviewed both the tour and http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, I still think this on topic; See my edit. How is this a "mind hack"?

Answer (score 1):

Well, unfortunately, you could tell them you're Bill Gates, but they'd still try to take you through the usual litany of turn it off and on again, check the connections, blah blah. Most of the 'technical support' people you talk to on the phone aren't techies at all, they're just ordinary people with a list in front of them that they take you through by rote, because they don't know anything. And it is fair to say that many of the calls they get are from people who've forgotten to connect something up, haven't read the instructions, or haven't turned the power switch on.

You could try telling them you're a software/hardware engineer or a Chief Technical Officer or something similar, and ask to be put through to an engineer who actually knows something.